# Return from button search results to be displayed on the same page in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I have created Search button that, when clicked, launches tree view results in a new window.
I want to have results in a tree view that is on the same page where Search button is, right below the Search button. Thanks for your help!

Here is how the view looks like:

[image]

Here is the py code:

```
class mrp_bom(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    def action_search(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        bom_ids = []
        pd_ids = []
        product_complete = []
        ptemplid = int(self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).product_tmpl_id.id)
        mbl_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom.line')
        id_s = mbl_obj.search(cr, uid,  [('product_id', '=', ptemplid)])
        for rec in mbl_obj.browse(cr, uid, id_s, context=context):    
            bom_ids.append(rec.bom_id.id) 
        for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, bom_ids, context=context):    
            pd_ids.append(rec.product_id.id)
        pp_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
        for rec in pp_obj.browse(cr, uid, pd_ids, context=context):    
            product_complete.append('['+ str(rec.default_code) + ']'+ ' ' + str(rec.name_template))
        print "\n\n Inside action_search() product_complete ", product_complete
        # raise osv.except_osv(('Message!'), ('Inside action_search!' ) )
        # vals = {'product_id' : product_complete}
        # print "\n\n Inside action_search() vals ", vals
        # return {'value' : vals}
        domain = [('id','=',bom_ids)]
        return {
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'name': _('BOM'),
         'res_model': 'mrp.bom',
         'view_mode': 'tree',
         'target': 'inlineview',
         'domain': domain,
               }
```

and here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
         <record id="action3" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Search BOM</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="domain">[('bom_id', 'in', active_ids)]</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="target">inline</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="bom_where_use_form"/>
        </record>
        <record id="ir_BOM_structure3" model="ir.values">
            <field eval="'client_action_multi'" name="key2"/>
            <field eval="'mrp.bom'" name="model"/>
            <field name="name">Search BOM</field>
            <field eval="'ir.actions.act_window,'+str(action3)" name="value"/>
        </record>

         <record id="bom_where_use_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">bom.where.use.form</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <label for="product_tmpl_id" string="Search BOM by Product" />
                <field name="product_tmpl_id" > </field>
                <button name="action_search" string="Search" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>               
            </field> 
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: A good question. Currently target takes this value => current, new, inline, inlineview. But these will not work for you.

Comment: That's right, Odedra. I have tried inlineview, it still replaces the search box and Search button with the tree view results. Any idea how I can accomplish to have search box, Search button, and treeview results, all on the same page?

Comment: sorry to say but i don't have any idea on these because on same page i cann't say anything because it works on `res_model` if it is same that it can be but with different `res_model` on same page i don't know :(

Comment: Odedra, I have updated my question with new code. Now py code and XML have the same res_model=mrp.bom. I am still getting searchbox and Search button replaced by tree view search results. Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: I'm concern with design part for example click on button and display blow tree view

Comment: User wants to see search box, Search button and list of search results on one page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67013/discussion-between-odedra-and-nebojsa).

Comment: why you are not using the default search view?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suppose that you rally have a reason not to follow the comment of  Atul Arvind - I don't see why you don't do it in the normal way. Simple tree view with attached to it a search view...

But let say that you (or your users) have some really more complicated scenario in mind where you need this search functionality inside some more complicated form. In this case I suggest you to use the `onchange` functionality of Odoo which is done in the 8th version with the help of the @api.depends decorator.

Consider the following example. I'm giving you just the Python code as I'm pretty sure it will be enough for you to see the whole idea:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api


class mrp_bom_search(models.Model):
    _name = 'mrp.bom.search'

    product = fields.Many2one('product.product')
    boms = fields.Many2many('mrp.bom', compute='_get_boms')

    @api.depends('product')
    def _get_boms(self):
        mbl_obj = self.env['mrp.bom.line']
        bom_lines = mbl_obj.search([('product_id', '=',
                                self.product.id)])
        self.boms = bom_lines.bom_id

mrp_bom_search()
```

I hope you see, beside the other, the simplest look of the proposed solution.